# How does TextCategorizer.predict work with spaCy?

Tags: label, classification, spacy, predict

I've been following the spaCy quick-start guide for text classification.

Let's say I have a very simple dataset.

```
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("beef", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 1.0, "NEGATIVE": 0.0}}),
    ("apple", {"cats": {"POSITIVE": 0, "NEGATIVE": 1}})
]
```

I'm training  a pipe to classify text. It trains and has a low loss rate.

```
textcat = nlp.create_pipe("pytt_textcat", config={"exclusive_classes": True})
for label in ("POSITIVE", "NEGATIVE"):
    textcat.add_label(label)
nlp.add_pipe(textcat)

optimizer = nlp.resume_training()
for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    losses = {}
    for batch in minibatch(TRAIN_DATA, size=8):
        texts, cats = zip(*batch)
        nlp.update(texts, cats, sgd=optimizer, losses=losses)
    print(i, losses)
```

Now, how do I predict whether a new string of text is "POSITIVE" or "NEGATIVE"?

This will work:

```
doc = nlp(u'Pork')
print(doc.cats)
```

It gives a score for each category we've trained to predict on.

But that seems at odds with the docs. [It says I should use a `predict` method](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer#predict) on the original subclass pipeline component.

That doesn't work though.

Trying `textcat.predict('text')` or `textcat.predict(['text'])` etc.. throws:

```
AttributeError          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-39e0c6e34fd8> in <module>
----> 1 textcat.predict(['text'])

pipes.pyx in spacy.pipeline.pipes.TextCategorizer.predict()

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tensor'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `predict` methods of pipeline components actually expect a `Doc` as input, so you'll need to do something like `textcat.predict(nlp(text))`. The `nlp` used there does not necessarily have a `textcat` component. The result of that call then needs to be fed into a call to `set_annotations()` as shown [here](https://spacy.io/api/textcategorizer#set_annotations).

However, your first approach is just fine:

```
...
nlp.add_pipe(textcat)
...
doc = nlp(u'Pork')
print(doc.cats)
...
```

Internally, when calling `nlp(text)`, first the `Doc` for the `text` will be generated, and then each pipeline component, one by one, will run its `predict` method on that `Doc` and keep adding information to it with `set_annotations`. Eventually the `textcat` component will define the `cats` variable of the `Doc`.

The API docs from which you're citing for the other approach, kind of give you a look "under the hood". So they're not really conflicting approaches ;-)